# Bukkit PlayerJoinEvent ERROR

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a minigame. If there are 2 players online, the countdown will start. I am testing this with my 2 accounts. When 1 account logs in, I get a diamond sword. Thats fine. But when I login with the second account, the countdown wont start and I get the an error. I don`t know what the problem is. Can you please help me? Thank you very much.

This is the error:

```
[15:41:29 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to Minigame v1.0.0
    org.bukkit.event.EventException
            at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
    va:302) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.jav
    a:62) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
    ava:501) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.j
    ava:486) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:
    282) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:142) [craft
    bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:115)
    [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:53) [
    craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:222
    ) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:168) [craf
    tbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:7
    44) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:3
    35) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:6
    28) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java
    :536) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at me.KevinGDev.Listeners.Player.PlayerJoin.onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoin.java
    :41) ~[?:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
    _60]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0
    _60]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1
    .8.0_60]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
            at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.ja
    va:300) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-53fac9f]
            ... 14 more
```

This is my PlayerJoinEvent:

```
public class PlayerJoin extends MListener {

    public static Minigame plugin;

    public PlayerJoin(Minigame pl) {
        super(pl);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();

        LocationUtilities.teleportToSpawn(player);
        InventoryUtilities.clearInventory(player);

        ItemStack is = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
        ItemMeta im = is.getItemMeta();
        im.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Kits");
        is.setItemMeta(im);
        player.getInventory().addItem(is);

        if(Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2) {
            ChatUtilties.broadcast("Enough players. Starting countdown!");
            plugin.startCountdown();
        }
 }
```

The PlayerJoinEvent is located in the PlayerJoin class.
The startCountdown method is located in the Minigame class (main class).

The startCountdown method:

```
public void startCountdown() {
    StartCountdown.timeUntilStart = 60;
    startCountdownId = getServer()
            .getScheduler()
            .scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new StartCountdown(this), 20l, 20l);
```

Comment: according to your stacktrace, you have a NNullPointerException in PlayerJoin.java Line 41.

Comment: the `plugin` variable is `null`

Comment: No, my plugin variable is:                                                                                               public class PlayerJoin extends MListener {
 
 public static Minigame plugin;

 public PlayerJoin(Minigame pl) {
  super(pl);
 }

Comment: @ DaGardner Please help me

Answer (score 2):

In your stacktrace I can read that you get a NullPointerException in your Event method "onPlayerJoin".

And I see the following:

```
public static Minigame plugin;

public PlayerJoin(Minigame pl) {
    super(pl);
}
```

You got two different "Minigame" objects. One you give to MListener and one that isn't initialized. And that should be your problem.
The "plugin.startCountdown();" call leads to a Exception because of this. You call the startCountdown() method on an object that isn't initialized ('null').

There are two options to solve this:

- initialize the plugin variable
- call "startCountdown()" on "pl"

So going with the first solution:

```
public PlayerJoin(Minigame pl) {
    super(pl);
    plugin = pl;
}
```

I don't recommend this as it is messy handling an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable variable.

Going with the second solution:

I assume for you it is somewhere possible to get access to the "pl" object (via getter or direct call). Use this in your EventListener instead:

```
 [pl/getPl()/getPlugin()].startCountdown();
```

Comment: I know a youtuber that has made some tutorials about Bukkit Minigames. Well, his Java knowledge is very poor. LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45JgCUXjkwk That code is very similar